# Combination and permutation of indistinguishable letters

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, permutations, combinations

In the movie scene in National Treasure (http://math.harvard.edu/~knill/mathmovies/swf/nationaltreasure.html), he tries to decipher the password with 10 letters but later finds out that there is one letter that is used again. I am trying to figure out how many words would it calculate with the 11 letters including the repeated letter.

11!/(1!*1!*1!*1!*1!*1!*1!*1!*1!*2!)

and the answer I get is 19,958,400 words

is this correct?

Comment: Could you please summarise the question you are considering in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Its the multinomial coefficient ${11 \choose 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2}$ which equals your factorial expression.